# Converting polygon with attributed into centered lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, fields-attributes, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion

I had some data points I wanted to aggregate with different road segments. So I buffered the road in order to process "Join Attributes by Location (Summary)". With the buffered road segments, I was able to use the *contain* feature here.

The problem was that the road lines transformed into polygons when I buffered them. Now I had to find a way to transform them back into the roads I originally had without them losing the attributes.

Does anyone know how this could work?

I already tried several things, but all failed. Also because some of them were not able to keep the attributes.

Comment: What did you try and what happened or didn't happen?

Comment: Why don't you join the attributes of the buffer back to the line road using again `Join Attributes by Location`?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without detour of creating a buffer, by simply "collect" the attributes of the N nearest points to each road.

Use the following expression in Field calculator of the road and rename `point` and `text` to the names of your point layer and the corresponding attribute field. Change the number of `7` to the N numbers of nearest points you want to get.

```
array_to_string (
    overlay_nearest ('point', text, limit:=7)
)
```

Alternatively, you can set a maximum distance from the road and get all points within this distance by replacing `limit:=7` with `max_distance:=10, limit:=-1` where `10` is the distance.

*Black label of the line is created using the expression from above:*
[image]